# Why is integer value not updating as a text?

Tags: c++, rendering, text

I have a space shooter game and I am trying to create a shield power for the player ship. My mechanic for shield is working. When I press the shield power button(P), the shield power decreases from 100 to 0 at a certain pace.

Problem is that I am trying to draw this shield power value on screen but it's just showing the starting shield power value(which is 100) and not showing the decrease in shield power value when I press the shield button.

What am I missing?

Here's the relevant code:
Game.cpp

```
if (keyboard->IsKeyPressed('P'))
{
    if (player_->shield == true)
        player_->shield = false;
    else
        player_->shield = true;
}

if (player_->shield && player_->shieldPower > 0)
{
    if (keyboard->IsKeyPressed(VK_SPACE))
    {
        XMVECTOR playerForward = player_->GetForwardVector();
        XMVECTOR bulletPosition = player_->GetPosition() + playerForward * 10.0f;
        SpawnBullet(bulletPosition, playerForward);
    }

    player_->shieldActive = true;
    if (GetTickCount() - player_->time > 100)
    {
        player_->time = GetTickCount();
        player_->shieldPower--;
        if (player_->shieldPower <= 40)
        {
            player_->shieldPowerLow = true;
        }
        else
        {
            player_->shieldPowerLow = false;
        }
    }
}
else
    player_->shieldActive = false;
```

TextClass.cpp

```
void TextClass::OnRender(System *system)
{
Graphics *graphics = system->GetGraphics();
FontEngine *fontEngine = graphics->GetFontEngine();
Player *player = new Player();

Game *game = system->GetGame();
game->RenderEverything(system->GetGraphics()); 

std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << player->shieldPower;

fontEngine->DrawText(buffer.str().c_str(), 50, 100, 0xffffffff, 
FontEngine::FONT_TYPE_SMALL);
}
```

Player.h

```
class Player
{
public:

int shootDelay;
int time;
int shieldPower;
bool shield;
bool shieldActive;
bool fullShield;
bool shieldPowerLow;
bool shoot;
}
```

Player.cpp

```
Player::Player() :
shootDelay(500),
shieldPower(100),
fullShield(true),
shieldPowerLow(false),
shield(false),
shieldActive(false),
shoot(false)
{
}
```

Comment: `void PlayingState::OnRender(System *system) { //...// Player *player = new Player();` ...am I reading correctly that you're constructing a new `Player` instance every time `TextClass::OnRender` is called?

Comment: Yeah. You are reading that right. That is the problem, isn't it? How can I go about using the "existing" player then?

Comment: `Player *player = new Player();` - this creates *another* player and asks what *that* player's shield power is. So now you have two players (one of which isn't used except to get its shield power). (And since it never gets deleted, after 100 ticks you have 101 players)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OnRender method needs to get access to several dependencies:

- Graphics
- Font Engine
- Player
- Game

And for three of the four you use one perfectly sensible pattern: a getter method accessible from the `System` you've been passed as an argument, or something get-able from it.

```
void TextClass::OnRender(System *system)
{    
    Graphics *graphics = system->GetGraphics();
    FontEngine *fontEngine = graphics->GetFontEngine();
    // ... //
    Game *game = system->GetGame();
```

But when it comes to the `Player`, you throw all that away and try to create a new `Player` from scratch:

```
Player *player = new Player();
```

Since this is a new instance, it always has the default values. Instead, we want to reference the *existing* player instance that Game.cpp is already updating each frame.

So, use the same pattern you're already using everywhere else: give `Game` a `GetPlayer()` method to return the player it's holding onto, and have the `TextClass` ask the `Game` it got from the `System` to get access to this existing player.